# Postfix SMTP banner show multiple hostnames

Tags: postfix

We have a Postfix SMTP server that's bound to two IP addresses and serves mail for two different domains. We can't change the domains to both use the same, single IP. Both IP addresses have reverse DNS

- 1.1.1.1 reverses to mail.domain1.com
- 2.2.2.2 reverses to mail.domain2.com

In our Postfix config I have

```
myhostname = mail.domain1.com
myhostname = mail.domain2.com

inet_interfaces = 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2

smtpd_banner = $myhostname Mail Server
```

(And some other stuff, which I think is irrelevant)

Using [MXToolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx), running the smtp test command on mail.domain2.com returns everything as OK, however running it on mail.domain1.com returns an error because Postfix is identifying itself as 'mail.domain2.com' in the SMTP banner, how do I get it to return the correct banner based on the external IP address used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to edit master.cf

replace the line starting with "smtp" with:

```
1.1.1.1:smtp  inet  n  - - - -  smtpd -o myhostname=mail.domain1.com
2.2.2.2:smtp  inet  n  - - - -  smtpd -o myhostname=mail.domain2.com
```

If you set one variable multiple times only one of them will remain.